# Should I handle a huge load of views in a separate Thread?

Tags: java, android, view

When loading a `Fragment` with a huge load of Views (100+) like

```
layout_settings_1 = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout_settings_1);
layout_settings_2 = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout_settings_2);

.
.
.

layout_settings_n = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout_settings_n);
```

Should we handle these assignments into a separated `Thread`?

*Please note: the `RelativeLayout` is just an example. It could be any type of `View`.*

Comment: A better solution would be to not use 100+ Views in a Fragment.

Comment: it tends to be an indication that something may be wrong when you get to 100 views in a single fragment and you are using all of them.

Comment: Actually I don't have to use them all at the same time. I know it may lead to a bad practice, however, client wants to run iOS on Android. That's basically why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, don't do that. Since you're not manipulating the View Hierarchy you may not get an immediate error/exception, but the android UI toolkit is not generally thread safe, so you have no idea what will happen if the View Hierarchy changes (on the UI thread) while you're running your findViewById (on another thread). Also, in order to actually use any of the view variables, you'd have to synchronise on something from the UI thread. I can't see any reason or benefit to do this.

From the official [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads):

> Additionally, the Android UI toolkit is not thread-safe.
>   ...
>   Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread.

Also I would like to point out that findViewById() doesn't actually "load" that view as it rather looks it up so there is not inflate going on. If you're worried about performance, worry a lot when inflating views and not when looking them up with findViewById.